# Kotlin Type Mismatch (interface is not resolved properly)

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, ktorm

I am using Ktorm and trying to create an abstract and generic DAO for my tables. In the end I get a type mismatch though and I don't see where I am wrong:

BaseEntity is an interface for an entity class with an id:

```kotlin
interface BaseEntity<T: Entity<T>>: Entity<T> {
    val id: Int
}
```

User (the ORM class):

```kotlin
interface User: BaseEntity<User>
```

IdTable (a table that has an int id as primary key):

```kotlin
open class IdTable<T : BaseEntity<T>>(tableName: String) : Table<T>(tableName) {
    val id = int("id").primaryKey().bindTo { it.id }
}
```

Users (SQL table):

```kotlin
object Users : IdTable<User>("users")
```

BaseDao:

```kotlin
open class BaseDao<E : BaseEntity<E>>(private val es: EntitySequence<E, IdTable<E>>)
```

UserDao implements the BaseDao:

```kotlin
class UserDao(val es: EntitySequence<User, IdTable<User>>) : BaseDao<User>(es)
```

Now as mentioned in the Ktorm docs I create an EntitySequence like

```
val Database.users get() = this.sequenceOf(Users)
```

and I want to create a UserDao:

```kotlin
userDao = UserDao(database.users)
```

But I get

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
EntitySequence<User, IdTable<User>>
Found:
EntitySequence<User, Users>
```

But `Users` is of type `IdTable<User>` as it inherits from it. Why does the compiler not know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Ktorm, so I won't help you with that part, but your problem is caused by [type variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance). Yes, you are correct, `Users` can be safely used as `IdTable<User>`. But that doesn't mean `EntitySequence<User, Users>` can be used as `EntitySequence<User, IdTable<User>>`. `T` type parameter of `EntitySequence` is **invariant** which means it can't be safely cast neither up nor down.

In order to safely cast `EntitySequence<User, Users>` to `EntitySequence<User, IdTable<User>>`, `T` would have to be **covariant**, so it had to be marked as `out` parameter. But it isn't.

In fact, by looking at the definition of [EntitySequence](https://github.com/kotlin-orm/ktorm/blob/master/ktorm-core/src/main/kotlin/org/ktorm/entity/EntitySequence.kt) I believe `T` could/should be marked as `out`. Then you could do what you need without problems. Maybe this is just a bug/oversight in Ktorm.

If I'm correct and `T` could be covariant, then it should be also safe to fix your problem by making an unchecked cast:

```kotlin
userDao = UserDao(database.users as EntitySequence<User, IdTable<User>>)
```

A long-term solution would be to report this to Ktorm developers - ask them to mark `T` as `out.`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have never heard about type variance, even though I have observed the <? extends E> syntax a lot. Casting solves my problem for now (even though it results in compiler warnings as it is an unsafe cast). I will post a question directly to the ktorm devs if they share your opinion that T should be marked as out.